Reliable way to insert record into SQL Server if one does not already exist
When I start my app I want to populate some table with data. This table has UNIQUE index on the field that needs to be unique.
SQLite has INSERT OR IGNORE syntax, PosgreSQL has INSERT ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING.
Failing the index is not an option as its very weird to start the app and immediately produce an error.
Browsing SO I found the answer which has a disclaimer that it will fail in the multi-user environment.
Is there a simple and reliable way of doing what I need?
The data in the table may change during the app run, so updating the records to the initial value is not an option.
Maye I should set some kind of transaction lock during the insertion?

It's not clear what is your concern. If it is about the unicity you can read the value first and select an appropriate value to write. If it is about the transaction it may happen an error and you should handle that in the application (even just after startup)

Are you after a MERGE statement? This will insert or update as needed, see the documentation

"Failing the index is not an option as its very weird to start the app and immediately produce an error." Why? I don't know the structure of your app, but you probably will know you are in the startup phase and can just ignore those exceptions ...

Have you had a look at EXISTS?

The first "duplicate answer" is exactly what I'm trying to avoid because it will fail on multiple environment.

And so is the second.

@Mark, how else i should phrase it? All I need is when my app starts it insert records in the table, but only once. All subsequent start-ups should not touch records inserted. There may or may not be new records to insert on each subsequent run.

@derpirscher, no I will not know where I am. Why?

@Mark, .moreover, I can't read and then insert. Imagine you and me both starting the app for the first time and connecting to the same DB. When I read the empty table that just being created I will insert new record. But you also read the same table and seeing that nothing is inserted try to insert the same record. But you portion will fail because record will exist and the app will finish with the error or it will succeed  and the table will end up with dupes. Both scenarios are unacceptable.

@JonasMetzler, no I am not. When the app starts for the first time, the table will be created and populated. During the application run the data in the table may or may not change.. when the app restarted, the data that already exist should be left alone and what ever new data if any will be inserted. My understanding is that MERGE is not a tool for that.

@Igor why if the second instance gets an error during write should terminate? It's not enough to do another read and do whatever is appropriate? You are the developer, you decide how to handle errors

@Mark, because it is NOT an error. If the insertion should be disallowed based on the record uniqueness, why it should be handled as error?

@Igor, because the app is trying to write a value and it is not written

@Mark, because it is already there. One .ore time - it is not an error. The write should silently be ignored.

Catch and ignore the error then. I don't get the problem. How the application behaves is up to you

Using IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON.
DROP INDEX ix_test_column ON test; -- if exists
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_test_column 
ON test(unique_column)
WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);

INSERT INTO test (unique_column, other_column)
VALUES 
    ('one', 'mary'),
    ('two', 'john'),
    ('one', 'jack');

fiddle

I presume it will still work if I have multiple users connected, right?

Yes, it's at index level, avoids checking for existance first, safe for multiple users.

and i presume the insert will not fail with error, right? As the SQLte behavior, for example, is to just ignore the inserting silently...

Yes, like SQLite's INSERT OR IGNORE it silently skips and ignores without raising any errors.
